# Send Paramets from HTML form to DVWP via javascript

Tags: javascript, data-view-web-part, filter, connection

Good day!

I have a DVWP. DVWP has parameters as query string "StartDate" and "DateEnd" and filters on datefield "Date" by parameters "StartDate" and "EndDate".

Also I have form on the page with javascript.

```
 function getparam()
 {
 var startdate = document.getElementById("datepicker").value;
 var enddate = document.getElementById("datepicker").value;
 var date = startdate.split("-");
 var stringstart = date[2]+"-"+date[1]+"-"+ date[0]+"T00:00:00Z";
 date = enddate.split("-");
 var stringend = date[2]+"-"+date[1]+"-"+ date[0]+"T23:59:59Z";
 var strUrl = window.location.toString()+"?StartDate="+stringstart+"&EndDate="+stringend;
 }

      <div id="panelDay" style="display:block;">            
         Choose Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"/><br/> 
         <input name="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="getparam()" /> 
      </div>
```

I'm not sure if i prepared the query string "strUrl" right.

Question: How can I send theese parameters to DVWP, so DVWP will be filtered?

I tried this  if( PreSaveAction() ) {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__redirect(strUrl)')}; but it doesn't work for me.

(And i don't want to use DateFilter WP for some reasons)

**Updated**
So I did This

```
  __doPostBack('ctl00$m$g_3375d095_c73e_4b32_86b1_d90170c4f5e2','NotUTF8;StartDate={'+ stringstart  +'};EndDate={'+ stringend + '}');
```

But I had to change my parameters from "QueryString" to "Postback;Connection;"   and it works now.   But I still can't figure out how should i use doPostBack with Query string paramters. 
    Should I use redirect?so i can see HTML code of this __doPostBack

```
 ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={http://myadd/sites/redirect.aspx?StartDate= stringstart&EndDate=stringend}')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to trigger the new Request. My solution would be to Request __doPostBack and handle your Params via the Request properties.
In your case it would be:

```
var dates = new Array();
dates [0] = stringstart;
dates [1] = stringend;
__doPostBack("Button1", dates );
```

In the code himself these could be accessed by:

```
Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.   I'm not very good in english. Could you explain what did you mean in last sentence?

Comment: In case of __doPostBack you'll send the information with an hidden field, not with the Querystring, so in the codebehind (or where ever you're analyzing the querystring). The values of the dates are stored in the hidden field, which is auto-generated by asp.
In code behind the call 
var x = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
will cause x to have the dates inside.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you have to do it via Querystring you can.

```
...
var strUrl = window.location.toString()+"?StartDate="+stringstart+"&EndDate="+stringend;
window.location = strUrl;
```

This should redirect the user to your site and make the params available in the querystring.

Comment: Thank you, but I tried this already. User redirects on the same page but witout query string parameters, like it was cut somehow...  I guess i should do doPostback anyway...